# How do i get the colour of a pixel in a picturebox control in visual basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Does anyone know a way to get the colour value of a pixel in a picturebox control when it is clicked in visual basic 2010?

I have created a small paint application which im using in a kiddies game but I do not want the children to colour over the outline of the image they are colouring in. So to do so I need to check if the currently clicked pixel in the picturebox is not black.

e.g. in pseudo code

```
if colour not black then
    Allow pixel to be changed to current colour 
else
     Do nothing 
end if
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way you can get a pixel from PictureBox:

```
Private Function GetColor(pic As PictureBox, X As Integer, Y As Integer) As Color

    If pic Is Nothing Then Return Nothing

    Using tmp As New Bitmap(pic.ClientSize.Width, pic.ClientSize.Height)

        Dim r As New Rectangle(0, 0, tmp.Width, tmp.Height)

        Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(tmp)
            g.DrawImage(pic.Image, r, r, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
        End Using

        Return tmp.GetPixel(X, Y)

    End Using

End Function
```

Just call it like this:

```
Dim col As Color = GetColor(PictureBox1, someX, someY)
```

Comment: Not really.  You forgot about PictureBox.SizeMode.

Comment: Thanks @Ken. I had to adjust it a bit because it was creating a blank bitmap. Il try edit your version above

Comment: De An is right, this *does* create a blank bitmap. You forgot to draw the image from the picture box into it.